# Macbook Pro M.2 SSD external check

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

My Macbook has defect RAM, so it won't run correctly. Now it also tells me, that something is wrong with my SSD (M.2-version). But it will not run a complete disk test - probably because of the ram-issue. ifixit shows that you can remove the ssd. Is it possible to place that into an external M.2 USB device and run it on another mac to check the ssd?

I ask that because my idea is the following: If the ssd is still ok, than I probably would try to change the logic board (because I cannot change the ram only), put the ssd back in and have a working macbook again. But if the ssd is defect as well, it does not make any sense to switch that too. That's just too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect a harddisk (also SSD) with another mac via thunderbolt or firewire. It will see it as external harddisk so you wont need to remove it from your macbook.

How to run a other macbook as external harddisk:

1. Connect the two mac's with thunderbolt to thunderbolt OR firewire to
   firewire
2. Power on the mac which has the harddisk you want to check and hold T to go to 'Target Disk Mode'.
3. The harddisk will be shown as external harddisk, run it with disk
   utilities to check the disk.

Check for more info the [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph19021)